# Is there an injection from the set of all real sequences to R?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an injection from the set of all real sequences
to R?

Comment: Yes, and if you bother to search the site, you might find the proof for that.

Comment: (There are possibly other threads discussing this statement in one form or another)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In fact there is an easy bijection, not that explicit, but it works.

Let $f: \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bijection (there are many, for instance continued fractions). The set of real sequences is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, that corresponds, from the above bijection, to the set of sequences of "sequences of naturals" $(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$.

But this last set is easily in bijective correspondence to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}^2}$, the set of double-sequences of naturals. Finally, $\mathbb{N}^2$ has a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, which you can chain again to obtain

$$
\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \simeq
(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N} \simeq
\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}^2} \simeq
\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: I dont really understand the bijection by continued fractions from N^N→R could you elaborate a little? Thanks for he help :)

Comment: Any non negative real number can be expressed uniquely as a continued fraction $$a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\frac{1}{a_4+\dots}}}}$$ where the $a_n$ are natural numbers. These coefficeints form a sequence of naturals, so this gives you an injection into $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can show there is a bijection with the following theorem.

> If $a$ is an infinite cardinal number, and if $b$ is a cardinal number
>   with $2 ≤ b ≤ 2^a$, then $b^a = 2^a$.

Also recall that $|\mathbb{R}| = \beth_1$ and $|\mathbb{N}|=\beth_0$. See also, [beth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). Thus we may argue as follows. $$|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| = {\beth_1}^{\beth_0} = 2^{\beth_0} = \beth_1$$

We deduce that $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{R}|$, or in other words that these sets can be put into bijective correspondence.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your solution went way over my head

Comment: @user116498, do you know about cardinal numbers?

Comment: Nope, sadly not only cardinality of power set

Comment: @user116498, you should look them up. Here's a primer: the cardinal numbers measure the size of sets. So unsurprisingly, $0,1$ and $2$ are cardinal numbers (because you have have a set with $0$, $1$ and $2$ elements), as are all natural numbers. But it doesn't end there; we can define cardinal numbers that measure the sizes of infinite sets, too. The least infinite cardinal number is $\beth_0$, and this is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$. A much larger cardinal number is $\beth_1$, and this is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, you should read up about them if you have the time.

Comment: Will do thanks :)